# Simulating the Router Firmware on a VM

Tags: router

I have a requirement to send requests to a D-Link DIR 601 (Firmware Version 2.00NA), for which I am trying to find any web site where I can download a firmware or an ISO which I can install in a VM.

Even, if i get access to any test target it would be good.

Comment: Why do you expect that D-Link is sharing his firmware in form able to running on VM? This is their know-how...

Comment: I am not expecting but there can be other sites providing such access.